# django-user-accounts : no such table: account_passwordhistory

Tags: django, authentication, account

There are a lot of django-related posts with "no such table" error but none are coming from django-user-accounts module.
I am getting this error

> sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: account_passwordhistory

, and here are the steps:

Installed django-user-accounts:

```
$ pip install django-user-accounts
Collecting django-user-accounts
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0c/4f/40f76395324d98b7f8717aad7e08ad6f86ba2714eb956be6070e0402988c/django_user_accounts-2.0.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (106kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 112kB 2.8MB/s
.
.
.
Installing collected packages: django-appconf, django-user-accounts
Successfully installed django-appconf-1.0.2 django-user-accounts-2.0.3
```

in settings.py added

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [ . . .
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'account' ]

SITE_ID = 1

MIDDLEWARE = [
.
.
.
    'account.middleware.ExpiredPasswordMiddleware',
]

ACCOUNT_PASSWORD_USE_HISTORY = True
ACCOUNT_PASSWORD_EXPIRY = 60  # number of seconds
```

restarted server and ran : $ `python manage.py user_password_history`

I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "/Users/ipozdnya/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute return self.cursor.execute(sql, params) 
File "/Users/someuser/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 328, in execute return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params) 
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: account_passwordhistory
```

I realize that account_passwordhistory did not get created at the time of install or some other step. `$ python manage.py makemigrations` states that `No changes detected`. Nothing in this doc tells me what to do about it: http://blog.pinaxproject.com/2016/11/22/how-configure-password-expiration-for-your-site/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, my problem was that I trusted the output of `$ python manage.py makemigrations`
that stated that `No changes detected`. However, when I did run $ python manage.py migrate, it applied a new migration for account_passwordhistory and account_passwordexpire tables just fine:

```
Applying account.0003_passwordexpiry_passwordhistory... OK
```

And the tables are in the DB.

Setting my password to expire in 1 second (`python manage.py user_password_expiry my_user_name --expire 1`) however did not have any effect on the site functionality, but that's a different issue.

Comment: `makemigrations` doesn't do a thing to database. It detects changes in `models.py` then make migration files. `migrate`, on the other hand, does check all migration files against database. If database isn't up to the latest migrations, then it will follow instructions in migration files.

All I'm saying that you haven't do anything to the database yet. That's why there is no such table error.

Comment: Understood. I did not run migrate because I thought there's nothing to migrate ("No changes detected"). Normally for the model changes I see the list of things I touched.  Turned out for the changes made to settings.py (INSTALLED_APPS in my case) are not reported by makemigrations the same way the changes done to models are reported.